# Toast message like android

Tags: jquery, css, cordova

Using this simple code we can create toast message in phone gap or web app
Javascript

```
function valiadteLogin() {
       var msg = "is required", errCount = 0;
       var pwd = $("#pwd");
       var email = $("#email");

       if (email.val() == "") {
          obj = email;
          msgObj = "Email "+ msg;
          errCount ++;
       }
       if (errCount > 0) {
          CreateToast(msgObj);
          //obj.focus();
          return false;
       }else
       {
          return true;
       }
   }
```

/*
    *Validation message popup
*/

```
function CreateToast(messageArg) {
    //alert($(window).height());
   $('body').find('.ToastMsg').remove();
   ToastMsg = "<div class='ToastMsg' onclick='ToastDismiss(this.id)' id='ToastMsg'><span>"+messageArg+"</span></div>";
   $('body').append(ToastMsg);
   var MsgWidth = $('#ToastMsg span').width();
   $('#ToastMsg').width(MsgWidth);
   setTimeout(function(){ToastDismiss('ToastMsg')},5000);
}
 function ToastDismiss(args) {
      $('#'+args).remove();
 }
```

CSS

/*
/*
    *Toast Message
*/

```
div#ToastMsg.ToastMsg{position: fixed;bottom: 10px;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.68);padding: 10px 20px;left: 0;right: 0;margin: 0 auto;width: auto;text-align: center;color: #fff;border-radius: 25px;}
div#ToastMsg.ToastMsg span{margin-bottom: 0;}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use the native functionality directly using [this plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin)

This will save you a lot of time in managing html/CSS/JS. and it supports all platforms like iOS,Android and Windows. So, you don't need to worry about platform compatibility.

```
window.plugins.toast.showShortBottom("Your toast message goes here.");
```

plugin has more customization options have a look at the [readme file](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

Try this light and simple [ToastMaker](https://github.com/vivekweb2013/toastmaker) library which creates toast notifications similar to android toast message. This is a small sized library with only **1KB** in size.

```js
$('#mybutton').click(()=>{ToastMaker("This is a toast notification!")});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/toastmaker/dist/toastmaker.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/toastmaker/dist/toastmaker.min.js"></script>


<button id="mybutton">Show Toast</button>
```

### Visit [API Page](https://toastmaker.wirehall.com/) to see more examples